# adjtime(x) adjusts time very slowly

Tags: c, time, adjustment

I'm trying to do `adjtime` to adjust the clock (which is, for example, 15 mins in future) supplying correct offset to `adjtime` function. But as I understand `adjtime` does it very slowly. So when I actually call the function and then check the time it remains the same.

How can I make a small adjustements (e.g. 1s to 1hr) so that effect appears immediately?

Thanks.

Comment: 1hr is not a "small adjustment".

Comment: "small" means <= 1hr, not 4 years :) may be it is not so small in case of adjtime (which has limits like 2145 sec).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of `adjtime` is to do so gradually and continuously in a way that does not break running applications which expect time to be continuous (and more importantly, monotone). If you use it correctly (e.g. via ntp), your clock should never drift by enough to require large adjustments like 15 minutes.

If you really do want to do a one-time large adjustment, use `clock_settime`. Just be aware that it could cause running applications to misbehave.

Comment: @maverik If you use adjtime correctly and often enough, it will have an effect similar to adjusting the frequency.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: Adjustement for 15 minutes takes way looong. I don't need adjusted time after 3 days, I need it now (in 1-2 secs).

Comment: @maverik: Then it sounds like you need to use `clock_settime`. But be aware that that could adversely affect other applications running on the system. If you run `ntpd` and have it properly configured, your system should maintain the correct time automatically.